# The Weak Turan Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

**The Weak Turan Theorem:** Let $G=(V,E)$ have $n$ vertices and $nd/2$ edges, $d\geq 1$. Then, the independence number $\alpha(G)\geq \dfrac{n}{2d}$.

In the proof of the weak Turan theorem found in *The Probabilistic Method*, let $S\subseteq V$ be a random subset defined by $P(v\in S)=p$ and the events $v\in S$ being mutually independent. Let $X=|S|$ and $U$ be the number of edges in $G|_S$. For each edge $e=\{i,j\}\in E$, let $Y_e$ be the indicator for the event $i,j\in S$ so that $Y=\sum_{e\in E} Y_e$. For any such $e,$ we have
$$E(Y_e)=p^2 \text{ and } E(Y)=\sum_{e\in E}E(Y_e)=\frac{nd}{2}p^2.$$
Since $EX=np$, $E(X-Y)=np-ndp^2/2$. Letting $p=1/d$ maximizes this quantity, giving
$$E(X-Y)=\frac{n}{2d}.$$
Thus, this implies that $\exists$ a specific $S$ for $|S|$ minus the number of edges in $S$ is at least $\frac{n}{2d}$. Select one vertex from each edge of $S$ and delete it, leaving a set $S^\ast$ with at least $\frac{n}{2d}$ vertices. $S^\ast$ is an independent set.

**Question: I understand that $S^\ast$ is an independent set with $|S^\ast|\geq \frac{n}{2d}$. However, I do not completely understand how deleting edges answers the proof of the Weak Turan Theorem with regards to the original graph $G$ as it requires having $nd/2$ edges. Why does deleting the edges still allow us to answer a question about a graph with $nd/2$ edges?**

Comment: They're not deleting edges, they're deleting vertices.  More specifically, for each edge $uv$, you delete either $u$, or $v$, and keep going until no edge remains.

Comment: @ManuelLafond as your comment complete answers the question, please consider adding it as an answer so the question can be formally answered.